# Why is my Ubuntu crashing

Tags: gnome, crash

I've been trying to run Ubuntu 20.04 on my system for a while now, and I've always run into this problem and I have no idea how to solve it. My Ubuntu is crashing randomly and the only thing I can do is force shut off, I've checked the syslog and it will have errors that I'm not too sure how to solve (like `gnome-shell[1407]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed` where when I look it up people will say it has been resolved). I'm running dual-boot with Windows. I've also checked the /var/crash directory and it has a lot of information that I'm not too sure how to parse, I see that there are `libc6.0.crash`, `libc6:amd64.0.crash`, `locales.0.crash`, `_usr_bin_x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd.1000.crash`, `_usr_libexec_xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.1000.crash`, and `_usr_share_debconf_frontend.0.crash`.

I have only recently started to use Linux and I was wondering if there is a way for me to check what is causing the issue? I've done a fair amount of research and tried many different things (like move to Nvidia driver, `apt update && upgrade`, checking filesystem (usb boot), checking SMART on my HHD, and even reinstalled Ubuntu), but none of these things resolved my issue, any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is actually causing each crash is detailed in each of those .crash files. Unfortunately, you cannot learn another entire language in one day, and --as you have discovered-- each of those .crash files can be highly technical. There is no simple solution. Either you hope that some nice person will read those crash files for you and interpret (so you must make them available somehow), or you must laboriously learn the languages. Were I in your shoes, I would focus upon enabling the first option, as there are many nice people here.

Comment: Probably you have a corrupted ISO installation! Do Re-download > Reinstall > Ubuntu to see if it still persists...and I didn't know that human eyes 'parse' code!

Comment: I agree your ISO may be bad. Here is the official install tutorial. It does nor include how to verify the ISO. Please download a fresh ISO. Verify the ISO before you make the Live Media https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I have tried reinstalling and even redoing the whole bootable drive with balena etcher a few times. everytime I boot up the usb it’ll say “1 corrupted file found”, is there a way for me to figure out what file it is n how would I fix it?